# How can I create a PDF from a Keynote presentation that uses a lot animations?

Tags: iwork-keynote

Problem: I have a big Keynote presentation where I make use of some animation capabilities. For example, inside one sheet I fade in a text, and after click another text, and an image moves from center to top. On the PDF all these things just look like in if the animation did not start. So both texts are merged into eachother with alpha transparency and not readable, and the image is behind the text. After clicking several times actually everything looks fine.

Is there a fancy way to make a useful PDF from that even if this animations are used?

Comment: There are things called slide shows that are meant to achieve this. Like say Power Point.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you export the presentation to PDF, there is an option

> Print each stage of builds

Tick this and you got it :)

Comment: Would I get like 100 pages for one sheet that's heavily animated? The only interesting thing is actually at the end ;)

Comment: Yes you would, but you can edit the PDF file later in Preview and delete the ones you don't want to have :)